# Function to get missing sequence from the list

Tags: javascript

I need to write a function in javascript that returns all the missing sequences from the list.

```
let arr = ['1', '2', '2.1', '2.2', '2.2(a)', '2.2(b)', '2.3', '2.5', '3', '3.1', '3.2', '3.2(a)', '3.2(b)', '3.2(d)', '4', '4.1', '4.1(i)', '4.1(iii)']
```

Then the result should be: `['2.4', '3.2(c)', 4.1(ii)]`

Below is the function that works for numbers only but doesn't work for the other sequence. Is there a way to get the desired result?

```
function findMissingNumber(inputAr) {
 // Sort array
 sortArray(inputAr);

 // finding missing number here
 var result = 0;
 if (inputAr[0] > 1 || inputAr[inputAr.length - 1] < 1) {
    result = 1;
 } else {
   for (var i = 0; i < inputAr.length; i++) {
     if ((inputAr[i + 1] - inputAr[i]) > 1) {
       result = inputAr[i] + 1;
     }
   }
 }
 if (!result) {
    result = inputAr[inputAr.length - 1] + 1;
 }
 return result;
}

function sortArray(inputAr) {
 var temp;
 for (var i = 0; i < inputAr.length; i++) {
   for (var j = i + 1; j < inputAr.length; j++) {
     if (inputAr[j] < inputAr[i]) {
       temp = inputAr[j];
       inputAr[j] = inputAr[i];
       inputAr[i] = temp;
     }
   }
 }
}

console.log(findMissingNumber([1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2]));
```

Comment: So what is the logic for the sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hei,so given this array

```
let arr = ['1', '2', '2.1', '2.2', '2.2(a)', '2.2(b)', '2.3', '2.5', '3', '3.1', '3.2', '3.2(a)', '3.2(b)', '3.2(d)', '4', '4.1', '4.1(i)', '4.1(iii)']
```

we can see that the parts we need to work over are

```
'2.3', '2.5'  -> missing 2.4

'3.2(a)', '3.2(b)', '3.2(d)' -> missing 3.2(c)

'4.1(i)', '4.1(iii)' -> missing  4.1(ii)
```

given this input, my very first idea to do this is actually loop over all elements and treat each one of them like a string, then check if the string is n chars long, and create a nested loop (to the one you have started with), that iterates over the elements with the same length. From there, you will check the ASCII code of those elements, and if the element of the X position has an ASCII code of Y, and the element at the following position, has ASCII of Y+2, you know you are missing a piece.

For the last case, the one with 4.1(i) etc, my input to help you out is simply make a count, that cheks how many 'i' there are. With the same logic as before, if the number of 'i' at the position Y is 2 times less than the number of 'i' at the position Y+1, you know you are missing something

Now, those are the idea I thought of. Mind that you'd need some string splits or anything that works with strings and convert into char, or string counters (like lenght method)

Comment: I am very thankful for your answer. Somehow it gives me an idea of how to solve this problem.